# React native: Cannot change package name - always failing

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm, package-name

at the moment I am facing a problem which I try to solve since 3 days already.. I want to rename my package name for my react native android application.

So, to be completely sure I am doing everything correct I have created a new project and tried to rename the package name. I have done this to be sure the error is not coming from my project and I haven't been able to fix my error yet.

I have initialized a new project like always: `react-native init MyAwesomeProject` .

Then I have replaced `com.myawesomeproject` in the following files with `com.awesome.project`.

/android/app/BUCK:

```
android_build_config(
...
package = 'com.awesome.project',
)
android_resource(
...
package = 'com.awesome.project',
)
```

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
package="com.awesome.project"
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.awesome.project"
    ...
}
```

Also I have replaced `package com.myawesomeproject;` with `package com.awesome.project;` and moved the `MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java` file from `android/app/src/main/java/com/myawesomeproject/`to the new path `android/app/src/main/java/com/awesome/myawesomeproject/`.

After I have done all those changes I runned `./gradlew clean` inside my android folder followed by this command `react-native run-android`.

However, I am still facing **exact** the same problem I am facing in my actual project.

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/max/Desktop/Max/MyAwesomeProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/myawesomeproject/MainApplication.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
             ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Also, I have already tried to add the following code to the top of the `MainApplication.java` file:

`import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;`

But I have added the code to the `MainApplication.java` located in `android/app/src/main/java/com/myawesomeproject` like it is saying it in the error output. If you do that, the console is not throwing any error after running `react-native run-android`, however, the App `myawesomeproject` gets installed and if you try to open it, the app crashes.

This clearly shows that react is still using the wrong path!

I even have tried the [npm rename package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) and runned the following command:

`react-native-rename "project" -b com.project`.

Not even this is solving my problem. I still get **exactly** the same error when running `react-native run-android`.

You guys can see the problem is not coming from my project cause I have exactly the same problem after I have set up a new project which is completely build from the scratch!

I would appreciate any kind of help! Thank You guys.

Comment: Can you share your manifest file.

Answer (score 9):

There are changes to be made in multiple files when re-naming. So it can get tricky. Using `react-native rename` makes it very easy.

### Using react-native-rename

I just tried setting up an initial project using: `react-native init MyAwesomeProject`

Then I ran: `npm install react-native-rename -g`

Then to change the name of the project I ran `cd MyAwesomeProject` followed by

`react-native-rename "project" -b com.awesome.project`

Then running `react-native run-android` it builds without errors.

#### Android Manually

If you plan to do the changes manually then there are a lot of files to change. There may actually be more depending on what you have added to your project. This is a guide for changing a vanilla project.

**In the application root**

In the `app.json` change the `name` and the `displayName` to be `"project"`

In the `package.json` change the `name` to be `"name": "project",`

**android/settings.gradle**

Change the `rootProject.name` to the name that you want: `rootProject.name = 'project'`

**android/app/build.gradle**

In the default config change the applicationId to the application Id that you want, in this case: `applicationId com.awesome.project`

**android/app/BUCK**

Change the package in both the `android_build_config` and the `android_resources` to the desired package, in this case: `package = "com.awesome.project",`

**android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

Change the package to the desired package name, in this case: `package="com.awesome.project"`

**android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml**

Change the app name to the desired app name, in this case `<string name="app_name">project</string>`

**Updating the *.java files**

This bit is tricker as you have to create folders, move files and then rename parts of the internals of the files.

**android/app/src/main/java/com/**

Create a folder called `awesome` and inside that folder create a folder called `project`

Copy the `MainActivty.java` and the `MainApplication.java` from the `android/app/src/main/java/com/myawesomeproject` into the recently created `android/app/src/main/java/com/awesome/project` folder.

Inside the both the  `MainActivity.java` and the `MainApplication.java` remane the package at the top of the files from `package com.myawesomeproject;` to `package com.awesome.project;`

Also in the `MainActivity.java` rename the string that is returned by the `getComponentName()` function to `"project"`

#### Manually iOS

It is a little tricker to do manually however it is simple to change the bundle id and the app name inside Xcode. I'm not about to go through the Xcode procedure as you have just asked specifically for Android.

Comment: using `react-native-rename` it's very messed, changed manually worked very well "android right now", Anyway Thank you you save my day ;)